# How to get query or param from URL and then use in Links?

Tags: queries, params

I'm trying to grab the query or param from an URL and then add it to an URL.

like products?price=15

How can I add the ?price=15 to a URL?

Like products/category?price=15?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [craft.request.getQueryStringWithoutPath()](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/craft.request#getQueryStringWithoutPath) like so:

```
products/category?{{craft.request.getQueryStringWithoutPath()}}
```

> Returns the query string, except for the `p=` param (which was probably added by your .htaccess redirect).

More complicated logic to avoid the **?** when the query string is empty (one of several ways to do this):

```
{# queryString will include '?' if we have one, otherwise '' #}
{% set queryString = (craft.request.getQueryStringWithoutPath() ? '?'~craft.request.getQueryStringWithoutPath()) %}
products/category{{queryString}}
```

Comment: But without query or param the URL's now have a "?" in it. Is it possible to conditionally hide or show the question mark depending if there is a query in the page url?

Comment: Johannes, try something like this: `{{ craft.request.getQueryStringWithoutPath() ? '?' ~ craft.request.getQueryStringWithoutPath() }}`, or better: assign the query to a var first.

Comment: @carlcs just beat me to it!